# HM-10 Wont accept name and returning +NAME=?

Tags: command, bluetooth-lowenergy, at-command, hm-10

Maybe someone had this problem.

```
"Send(AT)"
OK
"Send(AT+NAME?)"
+NAME=?
OK
"Send(AT+NAME1234)"
+NAME=1234
OK
"Send(AT+NAME?)"
+NAME=?
OK
```

Cant get this BLE HM-10 to remember name.
I was using FTDI and ch340, arduino monitor and realterm

Update!
After reset to defaults it started working Now i now its a genuine HM-10 and i have CC41-A

---

- Command             Description                      *
- ---------------------------------------------------------------- *
- AT                  Check if the command terminal work normally  *
- AT+RESET            Software reboot                  *
- AT+VERSION          Get firmware, bluetooth, HCI and LMP version *
- AT+HELP             List all the commands                *
- AT+NAME             Get/Set local device name                    *
- AT+PIN              Get/Set pin code for pairing                 *
- AT+PASS             Get/Set pin code for pairing                 *
- AT+BAUD             Get/Set baud rate                        *
- AT+LADDR            Get local bluetooth address          *
- AT+ADDR             Get local bluetooth address          *
- AT+DEFAULT          Restore factory default              *
- AT+RENEW            Restore factory default              *
- AT+STATE            Get current state                *
- AT+PWRM             Get/Set power on mode(low power)         *
- AT+POWE             Get/Set RF transmit power            *
- AT+SLEEP            Sleep mode                           *
- AT+ROLE             Get/Set current role.                    *
- AT+PARI             Get/Set UART parity bit.                     *
- AT+STOP             Get/Set UART stop bit.                       *
- AT+START            System start working.            *
- AT+IMME             System wait for command when power on.       *
- AT+IBEA             Switch iBeacon mode.                     *
- AT+IBE0             Set iBeacon UUID 0.                          *
- AT+IBE1             Set iBeacon UUID 1.                          *
- AT+IBE2             Set iBeacon UUID 2.                          *
- AT+IBE3             Set iBeacon UUID 3.                          *
- AT+MARJ             Set iBeacon MARJ .                           *
- AT+MINO             Set iBeacon MINO .                           *
- AT+MEA              Set iBeacon MEA .                        *
- AT+NOTI             Notify connection event .                    *
- AT+UUID             Get/Set system SERVER_UUID .                 *
- AT+CHAR             Get/Set system CHAR_UUID .                   *
- -----------------------------------------------------------------*
- Note: (M) = The command support slave mode only.         *
- For more information, please visit http://www.bolutek.com        *
- Copyright@2013 www.bolutek.com. All rights reserved.         *

  ---

+VERSION=Firmware V3.0.6,Bluetooth V4.0 LE

Answer (score 4):

Type to get value (Same is with other commands):

```
AT+NAME
```

Type to set value:

```
AT+NAMEnewName
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try equal sign for set a value

```
   AT+NAME=newName
```

edit for code prefix

Answer (score 0):

try a shorter name. I had the same problem.some version do not accept long name

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).